# Storing Nested foreign key django

Tags: django

I have model cake, pricing. Pricing is manytomany  to Cakes. Now in order model how i should store the values ?

```
class Order:
    service = models.OneToOneField('Service')
    price = models.OneToOneField('Pricing')
```

Since service is also linked to pricing, i cant create a order table like that.

Can somebody help out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you question correctly, but I guess you have to state a `related_name`, for example:

```
class Order:
    service = models.OneToOneField(Service, related_name='service')
    price = models.OneToOneField(Pricing, related_name='price')
```